# How can I use a SQL Server column of type rowversion?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, rowversion

With Visual Basic in Visual Studio I am trying to select a row of type rowversion from a SQL Server database.

'version' is a column of type rowversion

```
SELECT [Version] FROM Employees WHERE Employee_id = 1
```

Then in VB - To get value from version column

```
Dim myBuffer As Byte()  
Dim reader As SqlDataReader  
numRead = reader.GetBytes(0, 0, myBuffer, 0, 16)
```

I know there is data in mybuffer from this:

```
 For i = 0 To myBuffer.Length - 1  
    MsgBox(myBuffer(i).ToString())
 Next
```

Also myBuffer.Length = 9

But when I want to query my database with myBuffer...

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("version", myBuffer)
```

I get the error:

> Procedure or function 'updatePerson' expects parameter '@version', which was not supplied.

As if myBuffer in NULL.

Does anybody know to get the rowversion out of a database and then use it in a query?

Comment: [Can we please stop using `AddWithValue()`, already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) - also, have you tried adding the param with `@version` instead of `version`?  Also, what does your parameterized query/stored proc look like?

Comment: Try explicitly stating the type, it is possible `AddWithValue` is incorrectly determining the data type - `cmd.Parameters.Add("@version", SqlDbType.Timestamp).Value = myBuffer`

Comment: GarethD - Your answer does the trick. I did have to do ReDim Preserve myBuffer(7)